# How to attach a file to buildbot mailnotifier

Tags: buildbot

I know I can attach logs to buildbot using a flag. How do I attach another file (a zip for instance)? This doesn't seem to be a default option.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunatelly Buildbot can not send any attachments in emails (except logs and patches). 
But it use the Python Standard Library to work with emails.

You can customize an mail.py file writing own plugin to realize your function:
https://github.com/buildbot/buildbot/blob/master/master/buildbot/reporters/mail.py

See createEmail function

Python docs to work with emails:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.html